# .NET Debugging layout

Tags: .net, excel, logging

I have an Excel Add-In in .NET which sometimes crashes upon closing Excel. 
The type of crash is "Has stopped working" that describes an exception in some unmanaged code or in non-daemon threads.

I am trying to understand what's happening by inserting logging statement, however I would like to see more informations: the class of the caller, the time, the method and so on.

Is it feasible by using the .NET native logger or should I use a more complex logging library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time when you encounter such error, a comprehensive error log is written in systems event log. you can check it out at event logs > application and see what is going wrong.

It will be of row nature though and will give you the name of faulting module and the stack trace.

So far as you are in managed domain, it is possible to debug using the JIT debugger but as soon as you proceed to native code, you will not be able to debug as that code is made in release mode and does not have sufficient debugging information. You might see the disassembly though using the debugger supplied with visual studio.

Comment: This is all I have: Faulting application name: EXCEL.EXE, version: 14.0.6117.5003, time stamp: 0x4f622ef8
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.17651, time stamp: 0x4e211319
Exception code: 0xc0020001
Fault offset: 0x0000b9bc
Faulting process id: 0x4530
Faulting application start time: 0x01cd9f9059278b7f
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\EXCEL.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 5d418884-0b94-11e2-8bd0-b8ac6f2fd72d

Comment: and thats all you can expect except you are using some native debugging tools. Here is something which might help you - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidklinems/archive/2005/06/02/424595.aspx

Comment: Remember here that you are not trying to debug your code but the code of excel.exe itself so all you can expect is - at the most- disassembly of binary code. You might see some opcodes like push, pop, mov etc. If you are good at assembly languages, it might help you.

Comment: The problem is that, without my add-in, excel does not crash upon closing. I think it depends on the fact that there are some exceptions in some non daemon threads upon shutdown

Comment: My guess is, for some reason, your plugin is leaving behind some uncollected garbage. May be excel tries to communicate with the plugin while it is either unloaded from memory or it is not behaving properly to the shutdown message. However, this is just a wild guess. I am helpless to say anything on it.